# iOS swift double tap handle button and map

Tags: swift

I had mapbox map and few buttons on it. Problem is when user double tap any button maps zoom in. How to disable this? Even when user double tap zoom out, map is zoomed in and after that zoomed out. I try  but in iOS I don't know how, for android I know the solution. Below code doesn't work when double tap button map is zoomed in and also button delegate double tap ...

```
let singleTap4 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.tapPatrolaBtn))

    singleTap4.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap4.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    patrolaButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    patrolaButton.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap4)

    patrolaButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(multipleTap(_:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDownRepeat)


@objc func multipleTap(_ sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: UITouch = event.allTouches!.first!
    if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you disable it? this is a bad approach from the UX perspective.

Comment: if you understand, button tap I need for some action on map but with double click on button I don't need to map delegate zoom in! Even I have zoom in and out button and if user quick click on zoom out it always zoom in map because it's delegate map zoom in and after that button click and zoom out

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to handle double tap gesture too.

If you are using double tap gesture recogniser then double tapevent will not be delegate to mapbox map and mapbox zoom event wont call

Use below code for same:-

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(multipleTap(_:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDownRepeat)

//Don't do in action
func multipleTap(_ sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: UITouch = event.allTouches!.first!
    if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I already try this, but it doesn't work for me, I must to add also @objc to multipleTap, both are delegate button and map for double tap

Comment: I add it in my first post

Comment: When you double tap on button, is mulitpleTap button called or not?. If yes then please put return word to stop execution flow.. try this

Comment: Yes multipleTap is called, I first print to console to check this, after that I put return and still both are delegate and map and button when double tap

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, on button click I run this code so it disable map gesture for a while  :

```
mapView.isZoomEnabled = false

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.6) {
 self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = true }
```